# Is there a possibility of adding more statistics?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For example, it would be nice to see on what posts you've commented, how many comments you have made, ...

Also, for the sake of badges, it would be nice to see a "progress" statistic on the badges page where you see how far you are from getting a specific badge. For example next to the copy editor badge, you can see how many posts you have already edited.

Just a thought. I don't really edit posts for the sake of getting the badge, but sometimes I wonder. What are the general thoughts about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12205/jeroen-vaelen?tab=activity&sort=comments) might be useful to you...

For the second, you can use [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1953), but being based on the monthly data dumps, it won't be up to date with your latest edits.

For the third: edit only if you think you can justify whatever value you have added to the edited post.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the existence of SE queries.